# Connecting to NetSuite via Azure Data Factory REST API Connector

Tags: azure-data-factory, netsuite-rest-api

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am trying to establish a connection between NetSuite and Azure Data Factory using the REST API connector. I have successfully created a linked service for NetSuite in Azure Data Factory, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

(I used the Authentication type = "Base" and specified the base URL and username/password. When I test the connection it says that it was successful)

However, I am unsure about what specific details I need to specify in the Copy Activity to complete the setup and perform data transfer from NetSuite to Azure Data Factory:

[image]

Could someone please guide me on what settings or configurations I should provide in the Copy Activity to connect to NetSuite and import data from tables?
Also How can I get the data from a specific table?

Any help or sample configurations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add relative URL value?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same sort of issues trying to connect to Netsuite to retrieve data using ADF. What has been possible is connecting using a bearer token as below
[copy data source settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw09E.png)

This will then return a Json result to a sink which is stored in AzureBlobStorage, where it can then be copied through to your database.
However the drawbacks with this method are

1. The bearer token is only valid for an hour, before it needs refreshing, and still getting a few issues when trying to create that automatically. Can be done in Postman
2. A refresh token is required every 7 days which has to be manually created via logging into Netsuite.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).